# MOD_Rewrite Redirect URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have different URLS and different querys.

i.e.

I have mysite.com/login.php?u=user&pass=pass

i want to redirect to mysite.com/newsite/login.php?u=user&pass=pass

or

I have mysite.com/show?forum+id=34&topic=8

i want to redirect to mysite.com/newsite/show?forum+id=34&topic=8

i have about 30 links i would like to redirect to the newsite folder.

Is there wa way to redirect with out having to set all the urls in htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^show /newsite/show
```

This will redirect, for example:

> mysite.com/show?forum+id=34&topic=8

to:

> mysite.com/newsite/show?forum+id=34&topic=8

**Edit:**

Sorry, I didn't realise you wanted to do this with multiple URLs without having one for each one. I think this **might** work, but I haven't tested it.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.com /newsite/
```

If it doesn't work, you might need a / after the ^.com in the last line.

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mysite.com/device but it leaves off filename

Comment: If you look up mod rewrite directories, you should be able to find documentation on it. I'm sorry I couldn't help you further.